# React Native firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword how to validate login

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
   login(){
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
           firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) { 
                console.log(error.code)
                console.log(error.message)
                Alert.alert('Email', 'Error wrong credentials', [{text: 'understood'}]);
               })
                 navigate('SecondScreen')

        }
```

This is the current code the navigation works but the problem is as followed:

When I enter invalid credentials the navigate('SecondScreen') will still be activated

I only want to activate this when the login was succesfull.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only handles problems in the sign in. It does not yet handle the case where the sign in succeeds or when the user revisits the app/page (in which case they will automatically be signed in).

You will need to monitor the authentication state of the user as shown in [Get the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    navigate('SecondScreen')
  }
});
```

Comment: If I place this under render() it will still go to the next page without logging in. Where do I have to place this code?

Comment: The code registers a listener, which fires when the user authentication state changes. It only navigates to the second screen when a user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

In a very similar setup, navigate('SecondScreen') always failed on login, because the currentUser was always null when the page was navigated to. I found if I moved the navigation to a .then statement on the signInWithEmailAndPassword, currentUser was not null after the login.

I had a similar if (currentUser) { navigate('/') } function on the page being navigated to, so on login, it would navigate back to the login page, even though the login was successful.

This code seems to have fixed the issue:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const navigate = useNavigate();
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
function onRegister() {      
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch((error) =>
    console.log(error)
  ).then(cred => {
    navigateHome();        
  });     
  // currentUser is always null here;
  // navigateHome();
};
onRegister();

};

function navigateHome(currentUser) {        
 if (currentUser) {
   navigate('/')
 }
 else{
  navigate('/')
 }
};
```

Note: currentUser is still always null on login on the login.js page, but it is no long null on the page that was navigated to on a successful login.

Also, the user object is in "cred" of the .then statement on a successful login.